# Confusion on how to find derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am confused about the following, why do I get different results when I change the point where I use the substitution: (ie where am I making a silly mistake)

In both I use the substitution $$x = \cos\theta$$ so $$\frac{dy}{d\theta} = -\sin\theta\frac{dy}{dx}:$$

$$\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin\theta \frac{dy}{d\theta}) = \frac{d}{dx}((1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}) = (1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2x\frac{dy}{dx}$$

So far so good, but if instead I expand the bracket using the product rule:

$$\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} + \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\frac{dy}{d\theta} = \sin^2\theta\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \cos\theta\frac{dy}{dx} = (1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - x\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Where'd my two go!

Comment: What was the original question?

Comment: @Sahiba Arora I am just manipulating the expression $$\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin\theta\frac{dy}{d\theta})$$, it's actually part of solving laplace by seperation of variables but I saw I get two different results just based on if I sub in first or expand first so am confused. I must be doing something basic wrong. (edited question hopefully is clearer now)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. We don't know what is $y$. We don't know where you are substituting $x = \cos \theta.$

Comment: y is some function of theta, what is unclear?

Comment: If your substitution is $x=\cos \theta$, then $\frac{dx}{d\,\theta} = -\sin \theta$, i.e., $x\,dx= -\sin\theta \, d\theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because $\frac{dy}{d\theta} = - \sin \theta \frac{dy}{dx}$ doesn't mean that $\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} = \sin^2\theta \frac{dy^2}{dx^2}$. Indeed, if you take $\frac{d}{d\theta} \frac{dy}{d\theta}$, you get
$$\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2} = \frac{d}{d\theta} \left( - \sin \theta \frac{dy}{dx} \right) = (-\sin \theta) \frac{d}{dx} \left( - \sin \theta \frac{dy}{dx} \right),$$
and you can't simply $\frac{d}{dx}$ the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ term because $\sin \theta$ also depends on $x$. So you need to use product rule here instead.